# Handling duplicate keys in wordpress database

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm want to write a function that saves a user data array to a custom table in my wp database. I have this working with this function.

```
function insert_player($playerArray){
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "hots_logs_plugin";
    $wpdb->insert(
        $table_name,
        array(
            'name' => $playerArray['name'], 
            'player_id' => $playerArray['pid'], 
            'hl_mmr' => $playerArray['heroLeague'], 
            'qm_mmr' => $playerArray['quickMatch'],
            'comb_hero_level' => $playerArray['combLevel'], 
            'total_games_played' => $playerArray['totalGames']
        )
    );  
}
```

Now I want to extend this function so that if a duplicate `player_id` is sent the function updates the all the cells in the row apart from the `name` and `player_id`. The player_id is a UNIQUE KEY.

I have come up with this function, which I can't seem to get to work, and to be honest is a little over my head..

```
function input($playerArray){
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "hots_logs_plugin";

    $sql = "INSERT INTO $table_name(player_id, name, hl_mmr, qm_mmr, comb_hero_level, total_games_played) 
            VALUES(%d,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s) 
            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE(hl_mmr = %s, qm_mmr = %s, comb_hero_level = %s, total_games_played = %s)";

    $sql = $wpdb->prepare(
        $playerArray['pid'],
        $playerArray['name'],
        $playerArray['heroLeague'],
        $playerArray['quickMatch'],
        $playerArray['combLevel'],
        $playerArray['totalGames']
        );

    $wpdb->query($sql);
}
```

I just need a nudge in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I was really over doing it in my first attempt. The answer is actually really easy.

I just modified the original method to use `$wpdb->replace()` rather than `$wpdb->insert()`

The following method works great.

```
function insert_player($playerArray){
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "hots_logs_plugin";
    $wpdb->replace(
        $table_name,
        array(
            'player_id' => $playerArray['pid'], 
            'name' => $playerArray['name'], 
            'hl_mmr' => $playerArray['heroLeague'], 
            'qm_mmr' => $playerArray['quickMatch'],
            'comb_hero_level' => $playerArray['combLevel'], 
            'total_games_played' => $playerArray['totalGames']
        ),
        array (
            '%d',
            '%s',
            '%s',
            '%s',
            '%s',
            '%s'
        )
    );  
}
```

Comment: just browsing and i saw this, years later; if someone runs across this answer, be aware that `replace` deletes and re-inserts the data in question, which will change your primary key if it's auto-incremented. could cause trouble if you do it without realizing!